# Objective - Subjective text Classifier :

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am trying to built a classifier for subjective and objective text using imdb data . For objective data point I am using the movie's plot summary as input where as for subjective data points I am using review of the movies.

I took complete plot summary as one data point where as in case of reviews each review by a single user is a single data point .In my database different reviews of the same movie by different user is entered as different data points.

After this I cleaned the words of special character , removed stop word , calculated the Information gain to create the word dictionary and applied Naive Bayes  using word frequency to calculate the probabilities .

Now my question are

- Is my algo to build the classifier correct ?
- My classifer is heavvily biased toward objective. Am I making mistake
  in creation of training data ?
- I want to create a genric classifer that can be used for tweets or
  somthing extracted from blogs . Is movie review data is sufficient ? Right now its not working even for movie review data

Comment: first of all what are you trying to classify with the imdb data? Do you want to classify movies based on reviews?

Comment: I want to classify if the any incoming text (tweets , facebook post etc )  is objective or subjective .  Once I separate the neutrals then I will try to classify them into positive and negative sentiments

Comment: A SVM algorithm is much better suited for this task instead of Naive Bayes. Build a SVM classifier with bag-of-word feature vectors, with `tf-idf` encoding instead of frequency. You should see significantly better results. Of course, I can't say anything for sure, but subjectivity and sentiment classification generally follows this pattern to yield good results on movie data.

Comment: My objective data is paragraphs where as subjective data is oneliner or max two liner comments . Do you think this will make any difference ?